# Keyboard backlight wont turn on

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, asus, keyboard-backlight

I'm using an Asus UX410UAR laptop, but have been struggling to get the keyboard backlight to work over the last week, and would appreciate some advice from the community.

I have tried Bios versions: UX410UAR-AS.313; UX410UAR-AS.310; UX410UAR-AS.309; UX410UAR-AS.303 with no success. (313 causes system lockups on sleep, so currently running 310)

Distribution is Kububtu 22.04

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.11.20-051120-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

The current Grub option is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nosgx acpi_backlight=intel acpi_osi="
```

tried with and without: acpi_backlight=intel; acpi_osi=

in the "/sys/class/leds" folder:

```
input4::capslock  input4::numlock  input4::scrolllock  phy0-led
```

in the "/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi" folder:

```
als_enable  cpufv  driver  driver_override  hwmon  input  modalias  power  subsystem  uevent
```

output from "dmesg | grep asus":

```
[    4.266746] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[    4.282278] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
[    4.282366] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 9.0
[    4.282443] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x2021
[    4.282446] asus-nb-wmi asus-nb-wmi: Detected ATK, not ASUSWMI, use DSTS
[    4.282449] asus-nb-wmi asus-nb-wmi: Detected ATK, enable event queue
[    4.285129] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input8
```

Memtest86 run with 4 passes completed with no memory errors detected.

This issue seems to persist across multiple Linux distros I have tried on this machine. A second laptop I have of the same model number does not have the issue with the keyboard backlight.

Please let me know if i have missed anything to help diagnose the source of the issue.

edit: not sure if its relevant, but the main difference between the working and non working laptop looks be a missing OEM string in the DMI. Would this cause the backlight issue? [Comparison between both laptops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3zTt.png)

Comment: Is "OpenRGB" maybe something that would allow playing with settings for the backlight? (I got my G731 to "stay still" with OpenRGB, flashing lights might be cool, but only for the moment).

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, and i gave it a try via Appimage, however it didn't detect any devices.